# Deserialize / Serialize the AMF Request with PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, amf, amfphp

I have a problem with that. I tried using AMFPHP but it doesn't work correctly for me. I have the file with AMF serialized request. Now I want to deserialize it, and then serialize it again to test if that works. And there is a problem, because decoding is ok, but when I serialize it again, it is completely different than this in the file. I used AMFPHP 1.9. Code:

```
require_once( 'amfphp/core/amf/app/Gateway.php');
require_once( AMFPHP_BASE . 'amf/io/AMFSerializer.php');
require_once( AMFPHP_BASE . 'amf/io/AMFDeserializer.php');

$amf = new AMFObject(file_get_contents('a.dat'));
$deserializer = new AMFDeserializer($amf->rawData);
$deserializer->deserialize($amf);    

$serializer = new AMFSerializer();
$serializer->serialize($amf);

echo $serializer->outBuffer;
```

Also tried using SabreAMF [doesn't deserialize] and Zend Framework[no results yet...]

All I need is:
1. Deserialize the request.
2. Check the values, and change it if I want.
3. Serialize it again.

I thought it isn't too hard to do it, but now I see...

Comment: Hi, i am having the same problem. I can deserialize, and edit, but i cant reserialize. Did you find a solution?